# Azure Table Storage in Mule 4

Tags: azure-table-storage, mulesoft, mule4

Has any one used Azure Storage Module in mule 4? I have created a Azure Table Storage and using Mule connector "Add Entity" trying to add entity into the Azure Table Storage. But, its throwing following error **"java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.api.inputentity.EntityProperty"**

[image: Created Simple Flow]
[image: Azure Configuration]

[image: In postman, using POST request as below]

I tried "Get All Entities" which works perfectly and returns all the entities from the table storage.

Can someone let me know what am I missing in AddEntity?

[image: AddEntity]

**Error:**

```
ERROR 2020-07-17 11:58:18,374 [[MuleRuntime].io.07: [data-service-api].developer-dataService_Flow.BLOCKING @1a2866dc] [event: 6dfe3540-c7f6-11ea-affb-0edd2411b52f] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.api.inputentity.EntityProperty.
Element               : data-service-apiFlow1/processors/0/route/1/processors/0 @ data-service-api:data-service-api.xml:31 (Flow Reference)
Element XML           : <flow-ref doc:name="Flow Reference" doc:id="2e28df56-37c2-41d0-a84c-3c63687299cf" name="developer-dataService_Flow"></flow-ref>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.api.inputentity.EntityProperty
    at org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.internal.AzureStorageConnector.lambda$convertEntityProperties$1(AzureStorageConnector.java:694)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.internal.AzureStorageConnector.convertEntityProperties(AzureStorageConnector.java:692)
    at org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.internal.AzureStorageConnector.addEntity(AzureStorageConnector.java:675)
    at org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.internal.operation.AzureStorageConnectorOperations.addEntity(AzureStorageConnectorOperations.java:455)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.java:80)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.java:79)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ReflectiveMethodOperationExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodOperationExecutor.java:64)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.InterceptableOperationExecutorWrapper.execute(InterceptableOperationExecutorWrapper.java:60)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$null$3(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:149)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$executeWithInterceptors$9(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:149)
    at reactor.core.* (20 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (2 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at reactor.core.* (5 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a while, I've finally could make it work.

Create a Java instance of class `org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.api.inputentity.EntityProperty` and save it in variable `var1`.
2. Invoke method `setValue(String value)` (`setValue(java.lang.String)`) on instance `var1`; the `Args` for your example will be:

```
{ value : payload.Description }
```

Create a Java instance of the class `java.util.HashMap` and save it in variable `var2`. Invoke method `put(Object arg0, Object arg1)` (`put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)`) on instance `var2`; `Args` will be:

```
{ arg0: "Description", arg1: vars.var1 }
```

Create a Transform Message like this:

```
{ 
    partitionkey: payload.partitionKey, 
    properties: vars.var2, 
    rowkey: payload.rowKey, 
    tableName: 'Developer' } as Object { class : "org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.api.inputentity.Entity" }
```

At the `AddEntity` connector, the `Table` entity property will be set to the output of this `TransformMessage` (either payload or a variable of your choice).

The flow will look like this:

[image: Result]

This will save an entry in Azure Storage Table as expected. There may be options that are simpler, but this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the input. You didn't share the XML for the addEntity operation but it seems to be expecting an entity. Try adding a Transform element before the operation and with the metadata it may be able to let you view what input it is expecting.

Comment: I am passing the input in the Postman, POST request body

Comment: What is the content type of the input? What does the addEntity expect when you look at the Transform pane?

Comment: The content type is application/json and the expected input shows as "Any"

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of that?

Comment: I have added the screenshot to my original post.

Comment: All seems right at first blush, though I have not used this operation in the past. Are there more lines of the error in the log? The error returned to the client (postman) is just the description. Maybe the complete error plus stack trace can give some insight of the problem.

Comment: Yes at first it looked simple and straight forward connector but its not. Sad part is I couldn't find proper documentation at least on this Storage Table one.

One more thing I tried was, instead of inserting entity through Mule I tried directly inserting through client(Postman) using "Table service SA" URL and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is a problem converting properties, which should be org.mule.modules.azurestorageservice.api.inputentity.EntityProperty but it is passed as a String. I don't see any properties mentioned as such in the screenshot. The documentation doesn't clarify either.